# Windows & Lubuntu Remote Desktop Issues

Tags: lubuntu, remote-desktop

I am new to Linux and I have an issue I have installed Lubuntu which I plan to use as a headless server so I need to be able to remote desktop into it however after installing

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

and then using windows remote desktop connection in windows 8 I get the following screen after logging in using sesman-Xvnc

[image]

how can I get this so I can see the desktop normally I would just use Teamviewer but Iwant something I can use on my LAN and also I cannot set Teamviewer to start on boot like I can in windows

finally I did get it working using vino and Tightvnc on windows but before I would connect it kept asking on the Lubuntu screen to allow or deny someone accessing your computer is there a way to get this to auto-accept so i don't have to accept on the other end this being the headless Lubuntu server

Comment: If you open the Desktop Sharing Preference app, you can configure it to allow access without requiring a password. Do not mark the "Automatically configure UPnP router.." option. RDC/VNC clients should then have no problem connecting.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set vino to allow connections without confirmation.  On the headless server, open a terminal and type the command

```
vino-preferences
```

Remove the check besides

> You must confirm each access to this machine

[image]

Note: the dialog box in this screen capture is NOT configured correctly for your case, I include it only to show what the dialog box looks like.